# controlling what properties serialize to Json

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to control what properties are sent in my Json result.

Given...

```
    public class Result
    {
        public string SendThisProperty { get; set; }
        public string DontSendThisProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    { 
        var result = new Result();
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Is there a way to only return the property 'SendThisProperty'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `[ScriptIgnore]` to the property declarations that you don't want in the json, that should do the trick